# Use Arduino IDE to program Bluetooth Bee standalone

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-ide

Using Arduino IDE, how do I program the [Bluetooth Bee Standalone](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Bluetooth_Bee-Standalone)?  I can't select that particular board from the list under `Tools -> Board`.  The closest I see is Arduino Fio.